# Rename list of list and csv output

Tags: r, list, typeof, quantile

I'm trying to output some quantile results from a dataframe based of this:

```
result<- as.data.frame(tapply(df$Nbdays,list(df$Color,df$age),function(x)
round(quantile(x),digit=1)))
```

The I need the output to be something like:

[image]

while trying to output in xls:

```
write.table(res6,file='ChGenAgebis.xls',sep='\t',row.names=F,na='0',append = T,fileEncoding = "latin1")
```

I experienced this error:

> Error in .External2(C_writetable, x, file, nrow(x), p, rnames, sep,
>   eol,  :    unimplemented type 'list' in 'EncodeElement'

so Firstly how to output the dataframe  in xls

Secondly is it possible to rename the list of lists to have instead of:

```
    str(res6)

    'data.frame':   6 obs. of  5 variables:
     $ [0-25[        :List of 6
      ..$ Yellow : Named num  1.0    4.5    7.0 8.5 12.0
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "0%" "25%" "50%" "75%" ...
      ..$ Yellow : Named num  2.0    4.3    7.5 9.5 22.0
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "0%" "25%" "50%" "75%" ...
....
```

Because when I tried to change the col list name:

```
result<- as.data.frame(tapply(df$Nbdays,list(df$Color,df$age),function(x)round(quantile(x[,c("Min","1stQuartile","Median","3rdQuartile","Max")]),digit=1)))
```

I have this error

> Error in x[, c("Min", "1erQuartile", "Median", "3rdQuartile", "Max")] : 
>   incorrect dimension numbers

Any help ?

Comment: `write.table` will give you a `file.csv` that Excel can read in, but its not a `file.xls(x)`. Is that what you are after or do you want a true 'Excel' file?

Comment: I use xlsx::write.xlsx() to write excel files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an code snippet that may be helpful:

```
# example data
dat <- data.frame(color=sample(c("Yellow", "Green", "Red"), 100, replace=TRUE), age=sample(c("0-25", "25-50", "50-60"), 100, replace=TRUE), nbDays=rnorm(100), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
idx <- which(dat[,"color"]=="Red" & dat[,"age"]=="25-50")
dat <- dat[-idx,]

# calculate statistics
myfun <- function(x) quantile(x, names=FALSE, digit=1)
res <- tapply(dat$nbDays, list(dat$color, dat$age), FUN=myfun)

# transform res to data.frame
colors <- c("Yellow", "Green", "Red")
ages <- c("0-25", "25-50", "50-60")
colkeys <- c("Min", "1st Quart.", "Median", "3rd Quart.", "Max")
one_age <- function(age) {
    ans <- res[colors, age]
    for (cl in colors) if(is.null(ans[[cl]])) ans[[cl]] <- rep(NA,5)
    ans <- t(do.call(cbind, ans))
    colnames(ans) <- colkeys
    return(ans)
}
res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(ages, one_age))
```

In order to add a header line for the ages, consider using the `flextable` package, which supports several header lines. As already mentioned in the comments to your question, `read.table` can not write to excel, use e.g. the `xlsx` or `openxlsx`package instead.

Comment: It's really what I'm looking for; but now I'm trying to adapt it with my own date frame that already exist buy have NULL value on my tapply result when running the do.call() :

`res <- do.call(cbind, lapply(ages, one_age))`

Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  : 
  le nombre de lignes des matrices doit correspondre (voir argument 3)

So How to fix it ?